# Magento 2: Checkout page can't continue

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

For some reason, my checkout page is bugged, and I didn't change anything as far as I know. Usually, the flow goes like this:

`Add product > Go to cart > Go to checkout > Fill out details OR login > 'Place order'`.

If I log in to that detail page, I get to select my address from my account, which is good. And then I can continue. However, if I'm on a random page and login from there, and then go to my cart, I run into an issue. When I go to the next page (checkout), it remains blank. I only see the summary of items on the right side, but not the 'Place order' button, nor my address(es).

Also, this 'one-page refreshing' thing bugs me. When I have my email auto-filled in at the checkout page, I have to add and remove a character to have the javascript triggered to show the password field. Can't I just add a page in between this process giving people the option to choose 'login', 'register', or 'guest checkout'.

Hope someone can answer these questions.

Comment: Check for Payment Method & Shipping Method Enabled & Try to create Simple Product & Test

Comment: Payment en Shipping are enabled. This problem only occurs whenever I login before the checkout page. Logging in AT the checkout page or as new user seem to work fine..

Answer (score 0):

There was a javascript error causing this problem.

I solved it by setting Number of Address lines in `Stores > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options to 1 (instead of 2)`.

This is a common problem in 2.1.